# Is the theory of nuclear peace true?

Tags: nuclear-weapons

Taken from Wikipedia:

> Nuclear peace is a theory of international relations that argues that
>   under some circumstances nuclear weapons can induce stability and
>   decrease the chances of crisis escalation.

Is this true that nuclear weapons contributed to preservation of peace more than anti-war movement? I've found 2 studies that came to such conclusion but don't know if they're reliable.

*Kenneth Waltz*, political scientist from University of California and Columbia University, in monograph [The Spread of Nuclear Weapons](http://polsci.colorado.edu/sites/default/files/10B_Waltz.pdf) said:

> Nuclear weapons have been the second force working for peace in the
>   post-war world. They make the cost of war seem frighteningly high and
>   thus discourage states from starting any wars that might lead to the
>   use of such weapons. Nuclear weapons have helped maintain peace
>   between the great powers and have not led their few other possessors
>   into military adventures.

*Akop Nazaretyan*, cultural anthropologist and expert in collective behavior from Institute of Oriental Studies of the Russian Academy of Sciences, proposed [law of techno-humanitarian balance](http://www.helsinki.fi/iehc2006/papers3/Nazare.pdf) that says:

> The higher the power of production and war technologies, the more
>   advanced behavior regulation means are required to enable the
>   self-preservation of a society.

Comment: Not sure exactly how you would test this. I don't doubt that political tbeorists take guesses, and use statistics, but its probably just damned lies. Besides nuclear war, other factors have been promoted as lessening the chances of war; free trade; democracy; etc. Additionally, Nuclear Peace theory isn't that strong of a claim, "under **some circumstances** nuclear weapons **can** induce stability and decrease the chances of crisis escalation." With all those conditionals, it probably is true.

Comment: Seems to be true...until it's not anymore.

Comment: Its a theory not a proof or a law... so it is someone elses belief.  you can not challenge the truth of a belief just the feasibility of it.

Comment: One might argue that the risk of any open NATO/Russian conflict going nuclear has been a reason why the current Ukraine situation hasn't been escalated to a full-scale military conflict; but it's hard to say if that's the case - such questions usually can be answered only a generation after the fact, when memoirs are being written and old documents become declassifited.

Comment: @user1873 - easy to test. That's what game theory and psych experiments are for.

Comment: @DVK, random control? Who do we randomly decide gets the bomb?

Comment: @user1873 - me.

Comment: There are game theory principals at play in the nuclear peace theory. There are also some mathematical models that are helpful to describe the rationale behind nuclear proliferation between two actors. The classic example would the United States and the Soviet Union throughout the Cold War. The basic premise of these could be summed up as: 'As long as no single actor has a clear advantage, then the best move any individual actor can make is to maintain the peace.' I would affectionately refer to this as the Quark principal. The idea that more weapons promotes peace can be counter intuitive

Comment: cont... However, the longest period of relative peace time was initiated directly following the use of nuclear arms against Japan. There are also some more micro-level cases involving India and Pakistan as well as Israel and their neighbors. Others argue that these are the due to factors after World War 2 other than nuclear arms becoming more widespread. Many discussion on the topic fail to account for the rise of terrorism which is small scale relative to nation-state conflicts. Even the most pro-nuclear arguments concede that the fall of even a minor nuclear nation would be disastrous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current status quo is no country that has nuclear weapons has been invaded, which does seem to point towards possessing nuclear arms to be a strong deterrent of invasion. Post Cold War many non nuclear countries have been attacked/invaded showing that the U.N. or purely anti-war stances alone aren't enough to achieve peace. There is still some fighting between nuclear capable countries, notably India and Pakistan, but it's no longer the same intensity it once was.

Nuclear weapons could be the cause of the relative peace since the end of the Cold War, or it could simply be that the U.S. is really the only global superpower, and other countries resort to less blatant attacks that are less likely to result in U.S. intervention. It could also be that the U.N. is doing its job for the most part and keeping things peaceful and resolving conflict by diplomatic means, which has become massively easier in modern times.

Comment: can you give an example of any conflict resolved by UN in last 20 years?

Comment: @lowtech - sure. A conflict between UN bureaucrats and their low salaries. The UN won!

Comment: @DVK The UN has done a great job making countries that aren't the U.S. Russia or China feel important.

Comment: so you think it's mix of all factors or nuclear weapons play most significant part?

Comment: @Democrat I'd say its part nuclear weapons, part U.S. having a big enough stick that other countries will only fight about things that the U.S. would rather not use their stick for.

Answer (score -1):

Well it hasn't stopped ISIS bombing the UK. So it's probably not true. So far the UK hasn't dropped any nukes on ISIS territory.

It doesn't stop Ukraine/Russia fighting.

Having a nuclear weapon didn't stop 9/11. USA didn't drop any nukes on the Taliban.

Comment: Taliban, ISIS, and Al Qaeda are viewed as terrorist organizations, and not countries, by pretty much the entire world.  Terrorists don't play by the same rules that countries do.  Countries care if they get bombed into nuclear oblivion.  Terrorists not so much; if anything, they might see it as a great way to become martyrs and draw more members.  I think there are salient arguments to be made concerning the evolution of conflict post-ww2, and whether or not Russia is attempting to leverage nuclear fears to get its way, etc. I don't think this makes one, though.

Comment: Well, you can argue that ISIS are effectively a country or rogue state. Since they have control of territory.

Comment: @zooby A country is typically defined as such if it can claim a speficic region with borders, a population that belongs to it, and a regime that is able to enforce its laws and rules. ISIS might have (had) a specific region, and a regime that was able to enact force, but it lacked the populace belonging to it.  The actual number of ISIS fighters was relatively small, and most of the inhabitants of the region had to be suppressed. So no, ISIS was not a country in a classical way, and rather an occupational force.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy the question names 'stability' and 'crisis escalation'. You could argue that it doesn't really matter to a regular person whether their region is tormented by terrorists or state actors. Indeed, this answer illustrates (by example only) that nuclear weapons don't seem to prevent that disruption of the peace.